# Dart or JQuery with Google App Engine

Tags: jquery, google-app-engine, jquery-mobile, dart

Can you use JQuery or Dart withing Google App Engine - Like Google Web Tool Kit?

Regards
Christian

Comment: Show us the code you tried. I voted you down for that reason. See forum guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

AppEngine has nothing to do with Google Web Toolkit. The former is server technology, the latter client (browser) technology.

Answer (score 0):

It always helps to ask questions, then you find the answers yourself - Just found this:

http://news.dartlang.org/2013/02/dart-with-google-web-toolkit.html